# How to mimic POST to scrape a website in R

Tags: jquery, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'd like to download the COVID-19 data from this open store website: http://dashboard.publichealth.lacounty.gov/covid19_surveillance_dashboard/ automatically.

My idea is to scrape the website using to get the download link using `rvest`. However, the download link is hidden and only shows after I click the sidebar and go to the data page, while the website link remains the same. I searched for the reason and guess it's because the website uses AJAX.
[here is the picture of the downloading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDew4.png)

I tried to use `RSelenium` to mimic the click and download the data. It does work but it's slow and not so suitable, because I need the downloading process works as a function in the future.

Another method I have seen is to mimic the POST or to use `v8` (not sure if it helps here). I am not familiar with javascript, so after browsing dozens of similar questions I still don't know how to work it out. I don't know which POST I should mimic and don't know what information should be put into the POST function. It seems that 4 POST are loaded after clicking.
[here is the picture of the Network activities in DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6rCk.png)

I am open to any ideas and solutions that can work as a function. Thanks so much.

Comment: It might be easier to download the statewide data from here: https://data.ca.gov/group/covid-19 and then filter it down.

Comment: V8, being an ECMAScript engine, doesn't know what to do with a website, so in particular it can't be used to scrape one.

Comment: Thank you for the information @Dave2e! The statewide data is also useful for the project. However, I also need the point level data, so I still need to find a way to download it from that website. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @jmrk Thanks for pointing out that!